# What is the action of the field $\Psi_L$ on vacuum?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, chirality, helicity

Please help me to understand the following situation.

A fermion field $\Psi(x)$ acting on the vacuum can destroy a particle and create an antiparticle. If however, a chiral field $\Psi_L$ defined as $\Psi_L=\frac{1-\gamma_5}{2}\Psi$ acts on the vacuum, how does one argue that it creates a right-handed antiparticle. Please help me to show this.

Comment: If you mean by "vacuum" the vacuum state, then it must be destroyed by an annihilation operator. If $\Psi$ is a creation operator, then $\Psi^\dagger$ is a better notation.

Comment: @Vadim The question’s notation is standard.  Field operators in quantum field theory are a mixture of annihilation operators for particles and creation operators for antiparticles.

Comment: @Buzz you mean relativistic QFT. In condensed matter QFT operators can be defined differently - depending on how one describes holes. I suppose this is the key to the question: what is meant by "vacuum"?

Comment: [Here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/149307/are-there-really-left-chiral-particles) you can find the answer.